# Usage of akka ActorContext in integration tests

Tags: scala, integration-testing, akka-typed

We're migrating our project to typed akka Actors. We have services that can create actors at will, something like:

```
class Service(ac: ActorContext[_])
   def action() = { 
     ac.spawn(MyBehavior().receive)
  }
}
```

The problem arises when we're trying to test this service. It seems that we should only use `testKit.spawn` or `testKit.createTestProbe` methods. It works fine for unit-testing our classes.

But there is no way to get `ActorContext[_]` to pass it to services that are being tested.

So, it seems that that we are misusing the ActorContext in our service. But how a service can create a new actor?

I have an idea of passing a special `ActorRef[CreateActor]` that can create those actor. This way we can remove the dependency on `ActorContext[_]` in the `Service`, but I wanted to see if there is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not be passing `ActorContext` around, as many of the methods exposed in context are not thread safe.

You can create single `ActorSystem[SpawnProtocol.Command]` per JVM and pass around that to your services.

Then you can send `Spawn` command which takes typed actor behavior to injected actorSystem.

```scala
val echoActor: Future[ActorRef[Echo]] = actorSustem ? { replyTo: ActorRef[ActorRef[Echo]] =>  Spawn(echoBehavior, "echo-actor", Props.empty, replyTo)}
```

Do you really need to create actors from the service though?
Maybe you can have top level wiring where you create all the necessary actors and then inject `ActorRef` to your services.

Off-course if your actors are short lived and gets created and destroyed based on the demand, then what I suggested above makes sense.

Comment: For test, does it mean that I have to create a new ActorSystem ? Will it work with the actorSystem from TestKit? 
`class Service(ac: ActorSystem[SpawnProtocol.Command]) {...}`

As far as I can tell, TestKit doesn't provide a way to

Comment: ... create an `ActorSystem[_]`

Comment: Which testkit you are talking about?
BehaviorTestkit or ScalatestWithActorTestKit?

Comment: akka.actor.testkit.typed.scaladsl.ActorTestKit, I'm using it with specs2